# Git won't use second set of credentials when pushing to remote

Tags: git, github, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I've setup a second git identity to use with my company account, by creating a second ssh key and adding a `config` file to the `~/.ssh` directory, as explained [in this blog post](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574):

I have also set the new user name and email of the local repository:

```
$(path to repo directory) git config user.name "<Company account user name>"
$(path to repo directory) git config user.email "<Company account user email>"
```

as suggested in one of the comments in that blog post.

I've created a local repository, and one on Github (company account). I've added the (public) repo on GitHub as a remote (origin) of the local one.

I can pull from the remote, (using either the command line and  SourceTree), but when I try to push, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Permission to <company user name>/Test.git denied to <personal user name>.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

That is, git is trying to push using my existing, personal account, NOT the new, work one.

How can I have git push using the proper account's credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was the whole osx keychain/keychain helper thingy that might be to blame.

Here is how I solved it:

1) Delete local repo ("start from scratch").

2) Clone again from origin (GitHub).

3) Check that repo is configured to use new account's e-mail address (it was).

4) Check again hosts in .ssh/config file, make sure each is set up with the proper key (they were).

5) Out of desperation, assign the new `rsa` key to BOTH accounts/hosts in said `.ssh/config` file. still can't push, and still being addressed by old account's e-mail address (something's being cached somewhere...), hence can't authenticate.

6) Launch `KeyChain Access.app`, search for "git", "GitHub" and delete all "internet password" entries. **<- THIS DID THE TRICK**

After deleting everything, I had to re-enter my credentials for both accounts when prompted (SourceTree), but now I have two (working) repositories using two different GitHub accounts, side by side on the same machine.

Hope this helps someone.